# How to remove multiple values from array using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, array-splice

```
var array = [{
    name: "Mango",
    weight: "15gm"
}, {
    name: "Banana",
    weight: "10gm"
}, {
    name: "Apple",
    weight: "15gm"
}, {
    name: "Grapes",
    weight: "5gm"
}, {
    name: "Banana",
    weight: "15gm"
}];
```

**I want to remove all other than Banana.**

Comment: So the result array will be `[{name:"Banana",weight:"10gm"},{name:"Banana",weight:"15gm"}]`?

Comment: WoW! What a challenging requirement! What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
array.filter(function(x) {
    return x.name == "Banana";
});
```

So given this input:

```
[{"name":"Mango","weight":"15gm"},{"name":"Banana","weight":"10gm"},{"name":"Apple","weight":"15gm"},{"name":"Grapes","weight":"5gm"},{"name":"Banana","weight":"15gm"}]
```

We get this output:

```
[{"name":"Banana","weight":"10gm"},{"name":"Banana","weight":"15gm"}]
```

Comment: `callback
Function to test each element of the array. Invoked with arguments (element, index, array). Return true to keep the element, false otherwise.` Taken from the link in your answer

Comment: Yeah, exactly! So where the name is banana, the object will be included in the result array.

Comment: I'm confused, did you doubt your own answer?

Answer (score 1):

In above array when i remove array element using splice method my array length decremented by 1 so I have to consider index i. Following is a code to remove such objects.

```
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
   if(array[i].name !== "Banana"){
       array.splice(i,1);
       i--;
   }
}
```